Lattices of Lie Groupoids
There exists an important concept in Lie group theory being that of lattice.
Let $G$ be a Lie group, a lattice $\Gamma$ is a discrete subgroup $\Gamma \subseteq G$ such that the quotient $G/\Gamma$ has finite volume for the induced Haar measure.
I would like to know if there exists an analog for Lie groupoids and if it is well studied.
It should look something like this: Let $\mathcal{G}$ be a Lie groupoid, a lattice would be an étale subgroupoid $\Lambda \subseteq \mathcal{G}$ such that the quotient $ \mathcal{G}/\Lambda$ will have some sort of finiteness condition regarding the Haar system on $\mathcal{G}$.
I am not super familiar with Lie groupoids, but I know the quotient may fail to be a Lie groupoid, however this would be desirable.
With this in mind I am thinking of examples of Lie groupoids that admit lattices and my first thoughts are the holonomy and monodromy groupoids of foliations. On them can be constructed étale subgroupoids and I would like to know if in general the quotients by them would be Lie groupoids and if they could have a lattice strucutre.
If I was vague, feel free to ask more concrete questions. Thank you in advance.
